# How do I search for the phone number in my list (inside text file)

Tags: python-3.x

That's my text file:

```
["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]
["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]
```

And that's my code:

```
with open("repertoire.txt","r") as rep:
      liste = list(rep)
      print(len(liste))

      for l in range(len(liste)):
           if len(liste[l][4])==10 or len(liste[l][4])==14:
           res.append(liste[l])
           print("\n","Voici la liste de toute les personnes disposent d'un numéro de téléphone: ", res,"\n")
```

I want the program to send back the lines where there's a phone number inserted but I keep getting "out of range" error.

Comment: Does your text file *actually* contain the `[]`, `""`, and `,` characters?  Because, if it does, I don't think `list(rep)` does what you think it does.  What does your `print(len(liste))` show you?

Comment: It does yeah, it shows (5) which is the total number of my lines in the text file

Comment: `list(rep)` works fine when I need to delete a line, but not when I'm looking for a phone number inside my lines

Comment: Where are you getting this "out of range" error?  Which line?  Does `print(liste[l][4], len(liste[l][4])) show what you expect?

Comment: That's the error message: if len(liste[l][4])==10 or len(liste[l][4])==14:
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: It looks like `liste[l]` is a *string*, not a list.  What *exactly* does `repertoire.txt` contain?  Your `liste` does not seem to actually contain what you think it does.  What does `print(repr(liste))` show?

Comment: My text file contains this: `["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]
["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]` but the values are replaced

Comment: So, your text file *literally* contains that?  It *literally* has the `[]`, `""` and `,` characters?

Comment: The code works just fine without the text file, but it's not up to me to exclude the .txt. liste[l] is a list because of this variable `liste = list(rep)`

Comment: It does yes. I wrote my code so it would generate my text file like that.

Comment: The *elements* in `liste` are not what you think they are.  You have a list of strings, not a list of lists.

Comment: What is it then ?

Comment: You can find out by doing `print(repr(liste))`.

Comment: That's what it printed `['ï»¿##### phonebook #####\n', '\n', '["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]\n,'["Last_name", "Name", "birth date", "address", "xx xx xx xx xx"]']`

Comment: As you can see, you have an array of *strings* - lines from your file.  Your "list" is a string that needs to be *parsed* into a list.  *How* exactly did you make this file?  Did you `pickle` an object?

Comment: No, I didn't use pickle, I'll comment my add function

Comment: `with open("repertoire.txt","a") as rep:
         repertoire= [input("Quel est votre Nom: "),
         input("Quel est votre Prénom: "),
         input("Quelle est votre date de naissance (jj/mm/aaaa): "),
         input("Quelle est votre adresse (numéro et nom de rue): "),
         input("Quelle est votre Ville et votre code postal (Ville, XXXXX):"),
         input("Quel est votre numéro de téléphone (xx xx xx xx xx):"),
         input("Quelle est votre adresse mail (xxx@xxx.xx):")]`
         `print("\n",repertoire,"\n")
         rep.write(str(repertoire)+"\n")
         rep.close()`

Comment: Instead of doing `rep.write(str(repertoire)+"\n")`, I'd *highly* suggest creating a *parsable* format such as a CSV or JSON file.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the help man.